# Unsubscribe/Disconnect the real time update JS library

Tags: getstream-io

We are dealing with a SPA (single page application) so when the user logs in the UI refreshes without a page refresh. We also initiate the stream socket connection through the library like below. Now when the user logs out we want to destroy this. We tried **user1.unsubscribe()** and **client.disconnect()** but doesn't seem to work eventhough method looks defined in the source.

What's the right way to handle this in an environment where the page never refreshes?

```
  client = Stream.connect('xxx', null, 'xxx')
  user1 = client.feed('notification', @user.get('id'), @user.get('streamToken'))

  callback = (data) =>
    return

  failCallback = (data) ->
    return

  user1.subscribe(callback).then (->
  ), failCallback

  @user.on 'logged:out', ->
    user1.unsubscribe()
    client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to capture the binding returned from `user1.subscribe`, on this object you can call `unsubscribe` to cancel the realtime subscription. See the [Faye](https://github.com/getstream/stream-js#faye) section of the Stream-js library. Example code:

```
var subscription = user1.subscribe(callback).then(function() {}, function() {});
subscription.cancel();
```

Comment: `var subscription = user1.subscribe(callback);`

`subscription.then(function() {}, function() {});`
`subscription.cancel();`